# What observatories provide data similar to USNO?

Tags: astronomy, scientific-data

USNO(the United States Naval Observatory) generates positions for the celestial bodies(planets, moons,stars) and provide in a form of `.bsp` files and their Astronomical Almanac.

Is there any alternative open publication produced by EU or other big countries?

Comment: The Astronomical Almanac is produced jointly with the UK's Her Majesty's Nautical Almanac Office. The Institute of Science in St Petersberg produces the _Ephemerides of Minor Planets_ with details on the orbits and positions of asteroids. Neither is EU though...;-)

Comment: Astronomy stack exchange seems like a much better fit for this question. But please don't ask the same question on two different stacks.

Comment: @OrganicMarble thanks, posted there but without luck, so decided to post here additionally.

Comment: @astrosnapper thanks! didn't know about that one

Comment: @sigrlami crossposting the same question in two sites is strongly discouraged in Stack Exchange. One reason for that is that **it leads to answer and comment fragmentation**; a future reader finding an answer in one SE site may miss valuable information in an answer to the same question on another site. I see your [question in Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/37092/7982). We should close your question on one SE site where it will remain visible but direct readers to the other site for answers.

Comment: @astrosnapper which site do you recommend the question should stay open (see above comment)?

Comment: @uhoh ok, close it here

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's also posted in Astronomy where it is more likely to receive an answer https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/37092/7982

Comment: @sigrlami okay thanks! I've started the process, it will take a day or so depending on how quickly four more votes come in.

Comment: @uhoh seems to make more sense on Astronomy since it's concerned with observatories and their products for natural celestial bodies rather than human-made ones.